# Error with jQuery $.get

Tags: facebook, jquery

i can navigate to 
https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=20531316728 via my browser

but cant use jQ $.get , (not working with the specific url)

```
url='https://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=20531316728&width=292&height=258&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false';
$.get(url,  function(data){alert(data);} );
```

can i use any method to fetch the url (js is preferred ) ? any idea?

Comment: [curl?](http://php.net/curl) java/jquery cannot do crossdomain requests ... except json requests[ i hope i don`t do a very big mistake here]

Comment: If you are just trying to show the like box this should not be necessary. You should just be able to grab the code straight from facebook. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

Answer (score 0):

Simple, You cannot make cross domain ajax calls.

There are 2 options:

1) Try with JSONP Read - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

2) Make an ajax call to your site URL where you can use CURL to facebook URL to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

we could not access the cross domain data with ajax request

```
$.get("your_cross_domain_url",function(response)
{
});
```

So, you have to use a local file to accessing the cross domain data.

```
var content="your_url";
var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
// Filtering URL from the content using regular expressions
var url= content.match(urlRegex);
if(url.length>0)
{
// Getting cross domain data
$.get("urlget.php?url="+url,function(response)
{
// do your stuff
});
```

and the `urlget.php` file should be like this

```
<?php
if($_GET['url'])
{
$url=$_GET['url'];
echo file_get_contents($url);//loading the URL data.
}
?>
```